# Calling awt Frame methods from subclass

Tags: java, awt, processing

This question is about Frames, Java and [Processing](http://processing.org/).

This questions sounds pretty convoluted but its really not. I'll try keep this to a simple minimum. I'm creating a small ball in a maze game to get my head around physics and rendering. It's been a good experience so far but I've hit a bit of a brick wall.
The general layout I decided on was to contain PApplets within a AWT Frame and have the Frame close. The reason for this is because I was told that you should only have on instance of a Papplet at a time.

`PApplet` is the `Applet` class in [Processing](http://processing.org/), a rendering library.

I have 3 classes here including the main

```
public class Menu extends PApplet
{
//images and buttons 
PImage background, playbtn1, playbtn2, hsbtn1, hsbtn2, abbtn1, abbtn2, exbtn1,     exbtn2;
FBox pBtn, hBtn, eBtn;

FWorld menu;

//simple constructor
public Menu()
{

}

public void setup()
{
    size(600, 400);
    smooth();
    Fisica.init(this);
    menu = new FWorld();

    //loading and placing images
    background = loadImage("MenuAlt.jpg");
    System.out.println(background);
    playbtn1 = loadImage("play1.gif");
    playbtn2 = loadImage("play2.gif");
    hsbtn1 = loadImage("high1.gif");
    hsbtn2 = loadImage("high2.gif");
    exbtn1 = loadImage("exit1.gif");
    exbtn2 = loadImage("exit2.gif");

    //loading and placing buttons
    pBtn = new FBox(120, 150);
    pBtn.setPosition(135, 215);
    pBtn.setDrawable(false);
    hBtn = new FBox(120, 150);
    hBtn.setPosition(295, 215);
    hBtn.setDrawable(false);
    eBtn = new FBox(120, 150);
    eBtn.setPosition(455, 215);
    eBtn.setDrawable(false);

    //add item to world
    menu.add(pBtn);
    menu.add(hBtn);
    menu.add(eBtn);
}

public void draw()
{
    image(background, 0, 0);
    image(playbtn1, 80, 140);
    image(hsbtn1, 237, 135);
    image(exbtn1, 400, 140);

    mouseOver();
    menu.draw();
}

//close this frame an open a new level, high score or exit
//depending on what the use clicks
public void mousePressed()
{
    FBody pressed = menu.getBody(mouseX, mouseY);
    if (pressed == pBtn)
    {
        System.out.println("play game");
        this.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().setVisible(false);

        ExampleFrame x = new ExampleFrame(new Level("level1.txt"));
        x.setLocation(this.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getLocation());
    }
    if (pressed == hBtn)
    {
        System.out.println("high scores");
        this.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().setVisible(false);

        /* these are just for finding the parent
 System.out.println(this.getName());
 System.out.println(this.getParent().getName());
 System.out.println(this.getParent().getParent().getName());
 System.out.println(this.getParent().getParent().getParent().getName());
 System.out.println(this.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getName());
         */
        ExampleFrame x = new ExampleFrame(new HighScores()); //for testing, you can change this to new menu()
        x.setLocation(this.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getLocation());
    }
    if (pressed == eBtn)
    {
        System.out.println("exit");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

the exampleFrame class

```
public class ExampleFrame extends JFrame
{
    PApplet app;

    public ExampleFrame(PApplet emApp)
    {
        super("Ball Maze Game");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocation(200, 200);

        app = emApp;
        setSize(615,438);
        setVisible(true);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        add(app, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        app.init();
    }
}
```

the main

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ExampleFrame x = new ExampleFrame(new Menu());
    }
}
```

What needs to happen when mousePressed == ebtn is all the stuff in the Frame will be removed and a Highscores Screen will be loaded. highscores is almost the same as menu. There is no need to post code as there is enough here.

The second class is the one which acts as a frame and holds the PApplet

Bottom line, has anyone have any idea how to call the Frame methods from the PApplet or another way to remove all PApplets contents and load another PApplet in?

Comment: Is it possible to show your processing code??

Comment: @Favonius  Sure. its all posted now.

Comment: @OVERTONE: The code you posted has multiple compilation errors :( . And I think you have posted the hand modified processing `translated` java code. It will be nice if you can **1)** post the actual translated code by processing **2)** post the processing code you have written. Also, I think instead of `mousePressed == ebtn` you mean `mousePressed == hbtn` .. Right??

Comment: That code does not call the `Applet.start()` method.  Does the `start()` method do anything?

Comment: You changed your example code from Frame (awt based) to JFrame (swing based).  Do you know what gui technology your PApplets is based on?  It is highly recommended NOT to mix awt and swing components.

Comment: Apolgies. A friend made that change and i honestly did not see it until now. Im pretty sure he did that in order to make for a set default close operation. It can be based either in awt or swing becuase i wont be using either packages components. just their frames.

Comment: @OVERTONE: I added a link to [Processing](http://processing.org/). Either answer should be applicable, but it may help to clarify the dependency.

Comment: Haven't looked over the question too much, but isn't the whole idea of Processing to not have to deal with AWT or Swing ? (ie Basically to render everything yourself and not use prebuilt widgets?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to answer **How to call the Frame methods from the PApplet?**, I have modified your code snippet to bare minimum. In this modified version when the user click mouse button a `System.out` is fired.

Now there are two ways in which you can access your `Frame` object. But before that let me state these two points:

- When you create a PApplet like `new ExampleFrame(new Menu());` and add it in your `JFrame` like this `add(app, BorderLayout.CENTER);` then a complex hierarchy of windows/panels are created.

**Like this:**

```
javax.swing.JPanel
    javax.swing.JLayeredPane
        javax.swing.JRootPane
            test.ExampleFrame
```

- `PApplet` provides a public field for setting and accessing your frame object. And amazingly it is called `frame` :). You can set it before calling `app.init();`

**>>Code**

** Checkout the comments in the code**

**Modified ExampleFrame.java**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;    
import javax.swing.JFrame;    
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class ExampleFrame extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4792534036194728580L;
    PApplet app;

    public ExampleFrame(PApplet emApp)
    {
        super("Ball Maze Game");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocation(200, 200);

        app = emApp;
        setSize(615,438);
        setVisible(true);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        add(app, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Setting my frame object
        app.frame = this;       
        app.init();
    }

    // Sample Method
    public void sampleMethod(String msg)
    {
        System.out.println("I think '"+ msg +"' called me !!");
    }
}
```

**Modified Menu.java**

```
import java.awt.Container;

import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PImage;

public class Menu extends PApplet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6557167654705489372L;

    PImage background;
    static String tab = "";

    //simple constructor
    public Menu()
    {

    }

    public void setup()
    {
        size(600, 400);
        smooth();

        background = loadImage("C:/temp/background.jpg");
    }

    public void draw()
    {
        image(background, 0, 0);
    }

    public void mousePressed()
    {
        Container p = getParent();
        tab = "";

        // FIRST WAY OF ACCESSING PARENT FRAME
        while(p != null)
        {
            //printParentTree(p);
            if(p instanceof ExampleFrame)
            {
                ExampleFrame myframe = (ExampleFrame)p;
                myframe.sampleMethod("First Way");
                break;
            }
            p = p.getParent();
        }

        // SECOND WAY OF ACCESSING PARENT FRAME     
        if(frame != null && (frame instanceof ExampleFrame))
        {
            ExampleFrame myframe = (ExampleFrame)p;
            myframe.sampleMethod("Second Way");
        }
    }

    void printParentTree(Container p) 
    {
        System.out.println(tab+p.getClass().getName());
        tab +='\t';
    }
}
```

Checkout the `public void mousePressed()` method.

For completeness, I am also including Main.java.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new ExampleFrame(new Menu());
    }
}
```

Now to answer **Remove all PApplets contents and load another PApplet in**

Well I have not tested it. But you can add a `JPanel` to your `JApplet` and do all your drawing on that i.e creating child controls etc. When feel like redrawing then call `JPanel.removeAll()`. Which as per javadoc:

> Removes all the components from this
>   container. This method also notifies
>   the layout manager to remove the
>   components from this container's
>   layout via the removeLayoutComponent
>   method.

After this call `repaint` on the `JPanel`. Try it out, it might work :).

Comment: In fairness, note that this question relates to [Processing](http://processing.org/). Good luck on the bounty; I'm sitting this one out.

Comment: @trashgod: Yup I knew that. Even requested for the original processing code :O. In absence of that I just stripped down the presented snippet and used it for answer. Anyway thanks :)

Answer (score 22):

> What needs to happen when mousePressed == ebtn is all the stuff in the Frame will be removed and a Highscores Screen will be loaded

The demo. below of a nested `CardLayout` adds an `ActionListener` instead of a `MouseListener`.  It reacts to both mouse **and** keyboard input.

There are a multitude of other ways to include more than one GUI element in the same screen space.  Off the top of my head, `JTabbedPane`, `JSplitPane`, `JDesktopPane`/`JInternalFrame`, popping the high scores in a `JDialog` or `JOptionPane`..

#### Screenshots

[image: Game view]  [image: High Scores view]

#### CardLayoutDemo.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class CardLayoutDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Runnable r = new Runnable () {
            public void run() {
                final JRadioButton game = new JRadioButton("Game", true);
                JRadioButton highScores = new JRadioButton("High Scores");

                ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
                bg.add( game );
                bg.add( highScores );

                JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new 
                    FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));
                buttons.add( game );
                buttons.add( highScores );

                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5,5));
                gui.add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                final CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
                final JPanel cards = new JPanel(cl);
                gui.add(cards);
                cards.add(new JLabel("Level 1"), "game");
                cards.add(new JLabel("High Scores"), "scores");

                ActionListener al = new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        if (game.isSelected()) {
                            cl.show(cards, "game");
                        } else {
                            cl.show(cards, "scores");
                        }
                    }
                };
                game.addActionListener(al);
                highScores.addActionListener(al);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 good example. See also these [`CardLayout` examples](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/?s=CardLayout).

Comment: I keep telling myself I should check Rob's site (& a limited group of other sites, including yours) before drafting code.  But it's such fun.  ;)

Comment: Yes, I am completely shameless in citing yours and Rob's sites; feel free to link to mine. :-) Note [Processing](http://processing.org/), and good luck on the bounty; I'm sitting this one out.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  That clears up a few things.  I had thought 'Processing' was meant to be (the generic word) 'processing'!

Comment: Apolgies. I probably should have explained it was an external library.